# CUDA stream per-thread and library behaviour

Tags: multithreading, cuda

I'm using --default stream per-thread in order to issue kernels from 2 host threads in 2 non-default streams. All works fine until I want to use cudnn in both threads because any call to cudnn api will execute that api on the default thread.

I would like to run each cudnn api in the stream associated to the host thread which made the cudnn api call. I know I can use cudnnSetStream() to set a non-default stream but I need to get the stream that is associated to the host thread in order to pass it to cudnnSetStream().

How do I get, on the host side, the stream that is associated by cuda to the current host thread from which I want to call the cudnn api?

EDIT: I'm using C and ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: @Olaf ... you don't believe cuda uses C programming language so you removed the C tag and down voted ? :)

Comment: @RobertCrovella your suggestion cudnnSetStream(cudaStreamPerThread); worked great. Thanks

Comment: CUDA clearly is not C! Just don't spam  tags. As you acepted an answer which refers to `nvcc`, it is clear you don't use C. If that is wrong, the answer is wrong and, you need to clarify this with more than " I'm using C" showing **standard C** code! Just beacuse you use a similar syntax does not mean you do.Read [ask].

Comment: @Olaf quate from **How to Ask.** : "Try to include a tag for the language, library, and specific API your question relates to ... make sure they're relevant to the question you're asking!" I do think that C tag is relevant since there are cuda API implementations in other languages like C++, python, java just to name a few.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I also don't like the fact that you removed cudnn from the question title. My question is clearly about cudnn. Nice name by the way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a compiled library will not pick up your selection of `--default-stream per-thread` that you pass to `nvcc` when compiling your own code that calls that pre-compiled library.  You also cannot just set the null stream in this case.

In order to make the library use the default stream in this case, (assuming the library has a stream-setting function), you should use the `cudaStreamPerThread` stream handle, which is mentioned [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/stream-sync-behavior.html).

Something like:

```
cudnnSetStream(handle, cudaStreamPerThread);
```

or:

```
cublasSetStream(handle, cudaStreamPerThread);
```

or:

```
nppSetStream(cudaStreamPerThread)
```

This should also work similarly for CUFFT and other libraries that have a stream-setting function.